# iOS Facebook invitable friends requirements

Tags: ios, facebook, canvas, facebook-friends

we are trying to get a list of invitable friends by the following API [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0) but we're stuck at the moment.
By starting a FBequestConnection on "/me/invitable_friends" with the permissions "email", "public_profile" and "user_friends" we get no result with the error message "The operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 5.). Our Facebook app is currently in developement mode and has a canvas page set up. Are there any other requirments we missed?